# Unexpected char 0x20 at 3 in header name retrofit kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

```
@Headers("key : aW5kaWhvbWU", "Content-Type : application/json")
@GET("product_cat/5")
fun getProduct(
): Call<ResponseListProduct>

val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
val headerInterceptor = object: Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {

        var request = chain.request()

        request = request.newBuilder()
            .addHeader("key","aW5kaWhvbWU")
            .addHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
            .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
            .addHeader("postman-token", "6b02e1a7-87dc-c814-6545-65325bcd1d3d")
            .build()

        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        return response
    }
```

Comment: replace "key with "key"

Comment: is the same name ?

Answer (score 16):

0x20 is an space, I would assume 3 is the position, so try to remove those spaces between your key name and the two points (:). Something like: "key: value".

That should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when your header has a character that is not within utf-8. This happened to me when I tried to send a location in Denmark to an API via Retrofit. Something like this for example: ***Ertebølle***.

Because this word has the value ***ø*** the error would be `unexpected char at 0x5`

You can try to use base64 encoding to convert your string into characters that are easy to read for retrofit. You also need to find the right character-set. For example windows-1252 instead of utf-8. Here is a website that shows you how encoding/decoding looks like: https://www.base64encode.org/